# Increment Grid Ticks by 1

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic, extjs-chart

I want my Y-Axis on my grid to increment by 1 (for example: 1,2,3,4,5 and so on).

Currently I have it set like this:

```
axes: [{
    type: 'numeric',
    position: 'left',
    minimum: 0,
    increment: 1,
    title: {
        text: '',
        fontSize: 15
    },
    fields: 'total',
    grid: true
},
```

In my test data, the field 'total' current largest value is 3. If I set the 'maximum' on the axes to 3, it goes into decimal places and its increment changes to 0.2, but if I set it to 10, it increments correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set both `minimum` and `maximum` property. Add property `majorTickSteps` and set that to the difference between `minimum` and `maximum`. So: `minimum: 0`, `maximum: 3`, `majorTickSteps: 3`.